# Why doesn't Delayed provide a default method for compareTo?

Tags: java, java-8, default-method

The interface [Delayed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Delayed.html) requires any

> implementation of this interface [to] define a [compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) method that provides an ordering consistent with its getDelay method.

However I'm wondering, why there isn't a default implementation in Java 8, as `compareTo` is required by contract to depend solely on `getDelay`.

Is there a specific reason why this is left for the implementing class? Or is it impossible to create a default method when overwriting a super interface?

Edit: To make my question more understandable, here is an example:

```
interface Delayed extends Comparable<Delayed> {

    long getDelay(TimeUnit unit);

    @Override
    default int compareTo(Delayed o) {
      // might not be the perfect "compareTo" implementation, but you get the point
      return o == this? 0:
        Long.compare(this.getDelay(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS), o.getDelay(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    }

}
```

Comment: And how would the default implementation get hold of the necessary _object state_ to perform the computation? An interface has no state!

Comment: Not only that, but compareTo is highly specific to a class.  What would you order an `Object` by?  Its reference?  Its toString? Its hashcode?

Comment: @fge @Powerlord as stated above the `compareTo` method is _required_ to provide an ordering depending on `getDelay`, no other information required. Afaik a default method is free to call any sibling method or am I wrong?

Comment: You are not wrong but the _contract_ of .getDelay() itself means the Comparable contract can be violated if the delay has expired

Comment: I don't think so. If both delays have elapsed, `compareTo` should return 0.

Comment: @fge Well to be honest I still don't get the point, as both objects are expired for a _different_ amount of time and thus comparison by difference is still possible.

Comment: The contract is not well described. It simply says that 0 or a negative value means that the delay is expired. But it's not clear if a Delayed is free to return anything <= 0 if the delay is expired, if two elapsed delayed are supposed to be equal, or if the delay must continue to evolve in a natural, chonological way (i.e. 1 minute after the limit, it should return -1 minute)

Comment: @JBNizet with this remark I would have accepted fge's answer (which got deleted by somebody)

Comment: FWIW, all the implementations of the JDK, when compared to an instance of a different type of Delayed, use the same algorithm as in the question. When compared to an instance of the same type, they add an additional criteria: a sequence number, in case both instances have the exact same time. Given these implementations, I think the interface could have the default method you're suggesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is that `Delayed` exists since 1.5 and `default` methods exist since 1.8. So in order to provide the `compareTo` method as `default` method, the interface has to be deliberately *changed*.

If that doesn’t happen, there are several possible reasons:

- It might be that simply no-one ever considered it
- It might have been considered but dropped because either:

  - There might be possible compatibility issues
  - The expected benefits are not high enough to justify an API change
  - There were things with higher priority to do before the release

To me, it doesn’t look like a high-priority issue. Most of the time you encounter `Delayed` implementations in the context of `ScheduledExecutorService`s provided by the JRE and these implementations already exist and therefore won’t benefit from such a change.

I don’t think that you will encounter custom `Delayed` implementations in application code very often, but even if you see it different, the JRE developers obviously decided to focus on additions whose usefulness is more obvious (or less debatable).

---

Thinking about it, incorporating [the discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33918758/why-doesnt-delayed-provide-a-default-method-for-compareto#comment55599699_33918758) about the `getDelay()` contract combined with the `Comparable` contract, it would have been better, if `Delayed` never extended `Comparable` at all. After all, it’s not hard to sort objects by a property using a `Comparator` or similar design pattern.

Comment: Occam's razor suggests I should accept this until anyone provides a better reason